# UnityEngine.Microphone.devices.Length = 0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I encountered an issue while recording a sound in one of my unity app. Right after I launch my app, I click on a button that call this coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator coroutine_recording()
    {
        // Check if a microphone is present on the device
        if (UnityEngine.Microphone.devices.Length > 0)
        {
            //Check if user already gave authorization for using the microphone
            if (Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone) == false)
            {
                //Requets Authorization to use microphone
                yield return Application.RequestUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone);

                while (Application.isFocused == false)
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

                //Wait a bit so the device process the authorization and next step will not throw an error
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
            }
    }
```

While debugging, it appears that the device.length is equals to zero if call too early. When authorization is set, there is no error anymore.

Comment: A note on style: It is considered poor form to compare boolean variables to boolean constants and you should use the variable value directly. Eg, ```if (Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone) == false)``` should just be ```if (!Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone))``` (and note the boolean inversion, "!")

Comment: I did that for me just to directly read if I want to check a true or a false so I don't have a look for a small '!'. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a delay at the beginning of the code, waiting for the number of devices to be above zero. So, at the start of the coroutine, I added this:

```
//Wait until a microphone can be found
  while(UnityEngine.Microphone.devices.Length == 0)
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
```

This will make sure that you can use microphone.

Be aware to add a protection in case the device really don't have a microphone but this helped me here.